# django is authenticated false after calling login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django user is not authenticated in second view B if I call login in first view A :

**View A:**

```
login(user, request)
print(user.is_authenticated())
# True
```

**View B: (called after View A)**

```
print(request.user.is_authenticated())
# False
```

***Settings.py***

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )   
}
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**What makes authentication disapear in View B ?**

Comment: Please add more context to your question. How do you call View B ? What are View A and View B ? Django views ? function views ? DRF view sets ? DRF APIView ?

Comment: did you find solution if yes please help me